# Adding pyvista into pyqt widget?

Tags: python-3.x, pyvista

I'm trying to implement a pyvista plot

```
import sys
from qtpy import QtWidgets
from qtpy.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv
from pyvistaqt import QtInteractor


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, show=True):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        # create the frame
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        # add the pyvista interactor object
        self.plotter = QtInteractor(self.frame)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.plotter.interactor)

        self.frame.setLayout(vlayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)


        # Define a simple linear surface
        x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
        y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
        x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
        z = x*y

        self.grid = pv.StructuredGrid(x, y, z)
        self.z = z
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
        self.plotter.show_grid()
        self.plotter.add_mesh(self.grid, scalars=self.grid.points[:, -1], lighting=True, specular=0.5, smooth_shading=True, show_edges=True,
                              scalar_bar_args={'vertical': True})
        self.plotter.set_scale(xscale=1, yscale=x.ptp()/y.ptp(), zscale=x.ptp()/z.ptp())

    
        self.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

into a pyqt tab widget created within qtdesigner

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from pyvistaqt import QtInteractor


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 801, 571))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.widget = QtInteractor(self.tab)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-11, -1, 811, 551))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

but my attempts lead to various errors.
I am not sure what the proper information for these fields are

[image]

I've tried various base class types and names but I am really just shooting in the dark here as I am not very good at this yet.

Even before I attempt to add any of the pyvistaqt logic, it fails to load the basic tab widget template giving this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2f4308f7d135> in <module>
     46     MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
     47     ui = Ui_MainWindow()
---> 48     ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
     49     MainWindow.show()
     50     sys.exit(app.exec())

<ipython-input-1-2f4308f7d135> in setupUi(self, MainWindow)
     14         self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
     15         self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
---> 16         self.widget = QtInteractor(self.tab)
     17         self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-11, -1, 811, 551))
     18         self.widget.setObjectName("widget")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyvistaqt\plotting.py in __init__(self, parent, title, off_screen, multi_samples, line_smoothing, point_smoothing, polygon_smoothing, auto_update, **kwargs)
    223                 qvtk_kwargs[key] = kwargs.pop(key)
    224         with _no_base_plotter_init():
--> 225             QVTKRenderWindowInteractor.__init__(self, **qvtk_kwargs)
    226         BasePlotter.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    227         # backward compat for when we had this as a separate class

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vtkmodules\qt\QVTKRenderWindowInteractor.py in __init__(self, parent, **kw)
    258             else:
    259                 wflags = Qt.WindowFlags()
--> 260             QWidget.__init__(self, parent, wflags | Qt.MSWindowsOwnDC)
    261         elif QVTKRWIBase == "QGLWidget":
    262             QGLWidget.__init__(self, parent)

TypeError: QWidget(parent: QWidget = None, flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] = Qt.WindowFlags()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QWidget'
```

Can anyone help me out?
I find pyqt to be a very convoluted and difficult to follow library, and since I need a pyvista plot integrated into pyqt anyway, I'm hoping to get this plot working so I can toy with it in an attempt to understand the nonsensicality of pyqt.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest switching over to PyQT5, I believe PyQT6 is not yet supported.